# Transforming biblatex \printbibliography in an enumerate

Tags: biblatex

I would like to use biblatex's function `\printbibliography` to make long lists of conferences and papers in a reports, using biblatex.

I am using functions such as:
`\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword=my_talk]`
and
`\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword=my_article]`

Is there a mean such as instead of being shown as references, each would be transformed in a numbered enumerate list, of the kind:

1. My_talk_1
2. My_talk_2
   ...

and later

1. My_article_1
2. My_article_2
   ...

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer. I could obtained the desired result by redefining the bibliography environment:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\enumerate[label=\arabic*.]
     {}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endenumerate}
  {\item}
```